# QuickBox2D: Skin blending or transparency?

Tags: actionscript-3, box2d, skin

I'm wondering if I can lower the transparency of any skin in QuickBox2D, I have searched the documentation but I can't find it. Transparency value or filters(Multiply/Overlay). Anything is welcomed.

**Example:** If I create a movieclip, and make it overlayed and then call it through a QuickBox2D, it will become invisible.

**NOTE:** I want to blend skins with the stage background image.

Documentation: http://actionsnippet.com/qb2d/docs/html/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this [Tutorial](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/12/23/understanding-how-box2d-manages-collisions/) will help but it does mention in lines **45-47** that it changes the transparency.

See if this [link](http://www.physicseditor.de/tutorial-create-collision-shapes-for-box2d-flash-as3/) may help too.